# Modal Popup in IE submit button does not work

Tags: users, javascript

We are using the Ctools modal popup for registration.  In every other browser, this works.

In IE8 and IE9, after filling out the popup form, when a user presses "Create Account", the form disappears, and then pops back with all the fields empty.  In other browsers, it reroutes to the registration page.

I tried debugging in F12 developer tools but I'm not sure where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://drupal.org/node/1549934 for a potential fix.